# Eclipse Project > Configure

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, configure

I just happened to disable Maven Nature. Now to re-enable it again I was trying to do Right Click Project: Configure > Convert To Maven Project.

However I do not see Configure option anymore. How do I convert it back to maven project again? I deleted the project and re-checked it back from the truck but to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed the problem just by restarting eclipse. Looks like lot of inconsistencies arise if you operate Eclipse for too long. I guess its good practice to save work and restart eclipse every now and then.